# Python/MyPy: Changing the variance of generic typevar

Tags: python, mypy, typing, variance

I'm trying to add type annotations to a library that has linked node-like classes, and I'm facing a more complex version of the following problem.

Consider the below generic function:

```
T_contra = TypeVar("T_contra", contravariant=True)
U_cov = TypeVar("U_cov", covariant=True)
U_contra = TypeVar("U_contra", contravariant=True)
V_cov = TypeVar("V_cov", covariant=True)

def f(x: T_contra) -> tuple[U_cov, Callable[[U_contra], V_cov]]
    ...
```

It's generic in four variables, but in reality, `U_cov` and `U_contra` are not independent.  Is there any way to express that they need to be the same type, but have different variances relative to their containing types?  That is, have the type checker think of the function being generic like-so:

```
def f(x: T_contra) -> tuple[U, Calalble[[U], V_cov]]
```

So that mismatches in type U are raised as errors?

Here is a (still simplified) example of what I am after, this time with classes that are linked together, but otherwise behave similarly to functions (contravariant in their input and covariant in their output).  Node would need to be generic in all four variables for MyPy to not complain about this definition, but again, `T_cov` and `T_contra` are jointly determined like `U_cov` and `U_contra`.  The variance is relative to whether it's participating relative to up, self, or down.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type, Optional, Any

T_cov = TypeVar("T_cov", contravariant=True)
T_contra = TypeVar("T_contra", contravariant=True)
U_cov = TypeVar("U_cov", covariant=True)
U_contra = TypeVar("U_contra", contravariant=True)

# A Node takes a contravariant T_contra and 
# produces a covariant U_cov.  Like a callable, 
# if we require a Node that produces U, then 
# a Node that produces a more specialized 
# type V <: U will do too: Node[_, V] <: Node[_, U].
# Conversely, if we require a Node that operates 
# on type T, then a Node that operates on 
# a more general type S >: T will also work:
# Node[S, _] <: Node[T, _].
class Node(Generic[T_contra, U_cov]):
    def __init__(
        self, 
        # f is generic in the same types as Node
        f: Callable[[T_contra], U_cov],
        # up node has Any -> T_cov := T_contra
        up: Optional[Node[Any, T_cov]] = None
    ) -> None:
        # down node has U_contra := U_cov -> Any
        self.down: Optional[Node[U_contra, Any]] = None  # assigned by downstream node
        self.f = f
        self.up = up
        if self.up and not self.up.down:
            self.up.down = self
        elif self.up:
            raise ValueError(f"Multiply linked nodes not allowed yet.")
        self.value: Optional[U_cov] = None
        
    def update(x: T_contra) -> None:
        self.value: U_cov = self.f(x)
        self.down.update(self.value)  # <-- U_cov for self becomes contravariant for down (U_cov -> U_contra, which is T_contra relative to down in this class definition)
```

The aim is for something like this to type-check

```
def func1(x: int) -> str:
    return str(x)

def func2(x: str) -> str:
    return f"{x}.{x}"

def func3(x: str) -> float:
    return float(x)

n1 = Node(func1)  # type: Node[int, str]
n2 = Node(func2, n1)  # type: Node[str, str]; func2 and n1 compatability checked
n3 = Node(func3, n2)  # type: Node[str, float]; func3 and n2 compatability is checked
```

While this example would work with invariant `T` and `U`, in the more complicated cases, the variance becomes important.  For a simple example, consider that a particular node will often specialize the generic variables to, say, `class SomeNode(Node[float | Sequence[float], float]): ...`, so its up node can be of type `Node[Any, float | Sequence[float]` if the proper invariance can be expressed; otherwise, with invariant variables, it'd have to be `Node[float] | Node[Sequence[float]]`.